# angular 2 provide router parameters with every navigation

Tags: routes, angular

When navigating in Angular 2, we can pass parameters like so:

```
const uid = '1';
this._router.navigate(['/Frame', { id: item.id, uid}, uid]);
```

This will result in a route like this: 
*/index/frame/100?uid=1*

Here I have a parameter for the frame ID and a parameter for the user ID. Great, but I don't want to include the `uid` with every navigation.

How can one make sure the last parameter `?uid=1` gets included on every navigation? I'm thinking to towards a `provide` in the app bootstrap, something like this:

```
bootstrap(AppComponent,
[HTTP_PROVIDERS,
    provide(RouteParams, { uid: uid })
]);
```

But this is just a guess, any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you need value of uid always, then you can create a service which returns this value. You can inject it wherever required.

Comment: The value itself is already available wherever required, I need to provide the  uid routeparam with this value on every navigation